# Logical operations per component in GLSL

Tags: glsl, hlsl, opengl-es

According to the OpenGL spec in GLSL, the logical operators: `&&`, `||` etc work between booleans, not vectors of booleans.

So, what is the best way to perform the logical and/or per component in GLSL?

For example in cg and HLSL you can do this:

```
float2 x_ = ( (x >= 0) && (x < a) ) ? float2(0., 0.) : float2(0.5, 0.5);
```

I actually used this code on a cg script in unity and when it tried to convert it to GLSL I got this error:

```
Shader error in 'Sprites/Advanced': '&&' : wrong operand types no operation '&&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'vec2' and a right operand of type 'vec2' (or there is no acceptable conversion) at line 83 (on gles)
```

So, I am trying to find if something similar  exists in GLSL.